# snapSVG using the symbol element

Tags: snap.svg

I am very new to snapSVG.
In my project , i am having 40 reusable symbol element. 
Each symbol having the text and rectangle , so i wanted to change the text value and change the color of the rectangle.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the text attribute in Snap.

```
myTextElement.attr({ text: 'newtext' });
myRectElement.attr({ fill: 'blue' });
```

You can select with a css selector and Snap.select/selectAll( someCssSelector ) (or select/selectAll from a paper or container).

Comment: You can't change the text of just 1 element. You either need to move the text element outside of the symbol, or change the text of the symbol which will change it for all of the icons.